# BASH: Test whether string is valid

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Is there a way to invert this so that it checks if it is invalid first?

```
if expr "$string" : '-\?[0-9]\+$' >/dev/null
then
  echo "String is a valid integer."
else
  echo "String is not a valid integer."
fi
```

Comment: Did you try `if [ ! expr...]` ?

Comment: You don't need the `[ ]` to use `!`.  You can type something like `! false` right in the shell and see it succeeds.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, I agree with @nobody and @BenJackson, all you need is to add the 'logical NOT' operator , i.e.

```
    if ! expr "$string" : '-\?[0-9]\+$' >/dev/null ; then
    #--^  right there ;-)
       echo "String is not a valid integer."
    else
       echo "String is a valid integer."
    fi
```

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.